# Difference between F-measure and G-mean

Tags: python, metrics

I'm trying to understand the difference between F-measure and G-mean. I know they are harmonic mean and geometric mean but this didn't explain the relationship to the classifier's performance

Comment: How does this relate to [tag:python]? Looks like a question about statistics.

Comment: Because some python API use those formula as metrics

Comment: Consider posting this on stats.stackexchange.com . It seems like there will be more interest there.